# BulkUpdater Throws Error While it is executing an operation

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb, bulkupdate

I'm getting a error while executing `BulkUpdate` operation (Batch) operation on `cosmos db`.

I would also like to know how to pass the `partition key` to the `bulk update api` in java.

```
public void function() throws Exception {
        FeedOptions feedOptions = new FeedOptions();
        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
        DocumentCollection collection = null;
        collection = 
              documentClient.readCollection(collLink(outboundCollection), 
              null).getResource();
              feedOptions.setEnableCrossPartitionQuery(true);

          Builder bulkExecutorBuilder = 
          DocumentBulkExecutor.builder().from(documentClient, dbName, 
          outboundCollection,
            collection.getPartitionKey(), 1000);
           // Instantiate DocumentBulkExecutor
          DocumentBulkExecutor bulkExecutor = 
                     bulkExecutorBuilder.build();
        // Integer maxConcurrencyPerPartitionRange = 20;
        List<UpdateItem> updateItems = new ArrayList<UpdateItem>();
        List<String> documents = 
       shipmentDao.queryAsJsonList(outboundCollection,
            "SELECT  c.id,c.outboundShipmentMessage FROM c where c.outboundShipmentMessage.messageStatusInformation.messageDeliveryStatus='Reset'");
    for (String s : documents) {
        Outbound outbound = objectMapper.readValue(s, Outbound.class);
        options.setPartitionKey(
                new PartitionKey(outbound.getOutboundShipmentMessage().getBody().getLoad().getLoadId()));
        ArrayList<UpdateOperationBase> updateOperations = new ArrayList<>();
        SetUpdateOperation<String> valueToBeSet = new SetUpdateOperation<String>(
                "outboundShipmentMessage.messageStatusInformation.messageDeliveryStatus", "Retry");
        updateOperations.add(valueToBeSet);

        UpdateItem upval = new UpdateItem(outbound.getOutboundId(), "/outboundShipmentMessage/body/load/loadId",
                updateOperations);
        System.out.println(upval);
        updateItems.add(upval);

    }
    System.out.println(updateItems.get(0).getPartitionKeyValue());
    bulkExecutor.updateAll(updateItems, null);
}
```

The error message is as given below:

> {"Errors":["Encountered exception while executing function. Exception
>   = Error: {\"errors\":[{\"severity\":\"Error\",\"location\":{\"start\":103,\"end\":107},\"code\":\"SC2001\",\"message\":\"Identifier
>   'body' could not be
>   resolved.\"},{\"severity\":\"Error\",\"location\":{\"start\":108,\"end\":112},\"code\":\"SC2001\",\"message\":\"Identifier
>   'load' could not be
>   resolved.\"},{\"severity\":\"Error\",\"location\":{\"start\":113,\"end\":119},\"code\":\"SC2001\",\"message\":\"Identifier
>   'loadId' could not be resolved.\"}]}\r\nStack trace: Error:
>   {\"errors\":[{\"severity\":\"Error\",\"lo"]} ActivityId:
>   d1b379c0-b639-424f-ba72-5da5fb4cfedf, Request URI:
>   /apps/7eabec6a-5564-4682-acbf-478cb477a08d/services/8b7fe258-26a1-4c94-83bb-8c41d636700d/partitions/a9329586-72e4-4704-95d6-bfa8aaa014e7/replicas/131934252906091782p/,
>   RequestStats:  RequestStartTime: 2019-04-25T07:34:17.5277676Z,
>   RequestEndTime: 2019-04-25T07:34:17.5377703Z, Number of regions
>   attempted: 1 ResponseTime: 2019-04-25T07:34:17.5377703Z, StoreResult:
>   StorePhysicalAddress:
>   rntbd://cdb-ms-prod-eastus1-fd6.documents.azure.com:14065/apps/7eabec6a-5564-4682-acbf-478cb477a08d/services/8b7fe258-26a1-4c94-83bb-8c41d636700d/partitions/a9329586-72e4-4704-95d6-bfa8aaa014e7/replicas/131934252906091782p/,
>   LSN: 5807, GlobalCommittedLsn: 5807, PartitionKeyRangeId: 0, IsValid:
>   True, StatusCode: 400, SubStatusCode: 400, RequestCharge: 2.41,
>   ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: 5807, UsingLocalLSN: False,
>   TransportException: null, ResourceType: StoredProcedure,
>   OperationType: ExecuteJavaScript , SDK:
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.2.0.0, StatusCode: BadRequest.
>   Status code was 400